# How to activate Siri programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, siri

**My app's functionality can't use `"Hey Siri"` voice activation**.

Is it possible to activate Apple Siri programmatically in iOS 13/14?

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not invoke Siri programmatically in any iOS version at the moment.

Depending on your use case, you can use `SFSpeechRecognizer` to recognize the users speech or use `SiriKit` to accomplish a task using Siri.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @naglerrr! Could you tell me is it possble to activate Siri using a text field?

Comment: And one more question: can use call a Siri not using "Hey Siri" ?

Comment: No. You can not programmatically invoke Siri. Could you modify your question to include your use case? What do you want to do?

Comment: There seem to be ways to change the Siri activation phrase, but this is something the User has do do. You can not programmatically do this for him/her. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8319320

Comment: A case is simple – user mustn't know that it's Siri.

Comment: Ok. This is not possible. Even if you were able to programmatically invoke Siri, the Siri UI would show up and clearly give away the fact that Siri is being used.